# HTMLEditor. Extraer texto seleccionado con Clipboard

Tags: java, javafx

Cono obtener el texto seleccionado dentro de un HTMLEditor en javafx8 por codigo

Comment: La pregunta es amplia y carece de información para poder ayudarte, lo anterior generaría su cierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que interesante planteamiento el que tienes aquí, me di a la tarea investigar una forma para futuras referencias, y he dado con una joya, esta es una solución en github(gist) que ejecuta javascript para obtener el texto seleccionado, el script que ejecuta es este:

```
public static final String SELECT_TEXT =
            "(function getSelectionText() {\n" +
            "    var text = \"\";\n" +
            "    if (window.getSelection) {\n" +
            "        text = window.getSelection().toString();\n" +
            "    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != \"Control\") {\n" +
            "        text = document.selection.createRange().text;\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "    if (window.getSelection) {\n" +
            "      if (window.getSelection().empty) {  // Chrome\n" +
            "        window.getSelection().empty();\n" +
            "      } else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) {  // Firefox\n" +
            "        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    } else if (document.selection) {  // IE?\n" +
            "      document.selection.empty();\n" +
            "    }" +
            "    return text;\n" +
            "})()";
 WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
 Object selection = engine.executeScript(SELECT_TEXT);
 if (selection instanceof String) {
    absorbedWisdom.setText((String) selection);
 }
```

Realizando unas mejoras encontre que puedes omitir el Javascript anterior y utilizar esta forma simplificada:

```
String selection = (String) engine.getEngine().executeScript("window.getSelection().toString()");
```

Como menciono este ejemplo no es mío, pero es 100% funcional utilizando el Código de github.

> https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/7819195

Comment: Me parece bien la solucion. De hecho la conocia previamente. Pero el asunto es con respecto al HTMLEditor, porque el tiene un InputMethodRequest donde el toma el texto escrito pero el asunto es acceder a el. SI detallas mas, Antes de que el texto que uno escribe se convierta en html, primero es como una especie de texto tipo textArea....actualmente estoy revisando como esta compuesto el htmleditor para acceder a esos recursos. y luego poder extraer el texto seleccionado.

Comment: Otro punto es cuando le das click derecho aparecen la opcion de copiar, pegar....como sabe el htmleditor que texto se selecciono y como sabe donde el usuario la esta colocando cuando hace click en la opcion de pegar. He alli el dilema

Comment: Lo que sucede es que el HTMLEditor funciona con WebEngine por lo tanto es mas como un pagina web que como una aplicación desktop, lo que no se entiende de tu pregunta es que buscas con poder obtener el texto seleccionado antes de ser convertido a HTML.

Comment: Entiendo. Sucede que uso el HTMLeditor solo para aprovechar la posibilidad de escribir y formatear el texto libremente. Pero el asunto esta por ejemplo cuando del texto quiero seleccionar una cifra(500) y con un codigo aparte procesarlos ....convertirlos en letras y retornarlo en la posicion donde fueron tomados del editor. Un conversor de numeros a letras. Entonces la duda esta en como se cual texto esta seleccionado y como regresarlo a su posicion. Todo con el editor. estoy revisando el Clipboard...asi como el ContextMenu que el javafx lo agrega por si solo.

Comment: y no te seria mas fácil que el usuario marcara los valores que vas a procesar por ejemplo con el resaltado o highlighter o con un boton personalizado que agregue un propiedad al texto y al presionar un botón extraes esas fragmentos de HTML los procesas, los editas y remplazas en el HTML para luego volver a hacer set del nuevo HTML. Porque las únicas opciones que veo todas son utilizando Javascript para realizar ese grado de detalle que buscar.

Comment: También estoy de acuerdo.